# Angular given the problem when I am trying to install the dependecy through 'npm install'

Tags: angular, spring-boot

This is my angular configuration like ng version

```
. ng version

Angular CLI: 16.1.4`your text`
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: linux x64
```

Angular:
...

```
 Package                      Version
 ------------------------------------------------
 @angular-devkit/architect    0.`your text`1601.4
 @angular-devkit/core         16.1.4
 @angular-devkit/schematics   16.1.4
 @schematics/angular          16.1.4
```

output: `your text`

but when I am trying to install: `npm install`
this gives me an error:

```
"npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs"
```

I want to setup my angular application window to Ubuntu.